# Case When Same Values In Multiple Groups

Tags: sql, teradata

I want to create 3+ groups of people, but my issue is that some items fall within multiple groups (there are various sub groups). When using a case when statement I am unable to reproduce those results, as the first time it sees that result it is counted, and then ignored in the next when statement.

```
Select Column1, Column2, 
CASE
    WHEN(number IN (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8)) then 'Group1' 
    WHEN(number IN (1,2,3,4)) then 'Group2' 
    WHEN(number IN (9,10,11,12)) then 'Group3' 
    ELSE 'Group4' END 
AS Categories,
SUM(Gross_Sales)
```

Group 1 will have everything I want, Group 2 is empty (as expected when using a case when), and then group 3 will have everything I want. How would I go about re-writing this?

Let's say my table contains the following data:

```
|     Number          |     Gross_Sales  |
|---------------------|------------------|
|          1          |         10       |
|---------------------|------------------|
|          2          |         10       |
|---------------------|------------------|
|          8          |         10       |
|---------------------|------------------|
```

I want the output to display as:

Group1: 30
Group2: 20
Group3: 0

Currently this returns:

Group1: 30
Group2: 0
Group3: 0

Comment: if a record has `number` = 1 what value do you want to see in the column? `Group1` or `Group2`. You are only creating one new column that can take only one value against a given record.

Comment: If it were in more than one `Group` how would you want that output? `Field1Value`, `Field2Value`, `Group1;Group2;Group4` ??? It would be helpful if you could add sample data and your desired results.

Comment: Sorry maybe I should have specified better. This is actually just a snip of my code. After this comes several SUMs where I am trying to calculate Gross Sales, Net Sales, etc.

So when number = 1, I want to see it included in the gross sales of BOTH Group1 and Group2. Not just within Group 1

Comment: A table has _columns_, not fields.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think a UNION will be the best way to solve this one:

```
Select Column1, Column2, 
CASE WHEN(number IN (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8)) then 'Group1' as categories    
FROM ...

UNION ALL

Select Column1, Column2, 
CASE WHEN(number IN (1,2,3,4)) then 'Group2' as categories    
FROM ...

UNION ALL

Select Column1, Column2, 
CASE WHEN(number IN (9,10,11,12)) then 'Group3' as categories    
FROM ...

UNION ALL

Select Column1, Column2, 
CASE WHEN(number NOT BETWEEN 1 AND 12) then 'Group4' as categories    
FROM ...
```

You may want to run this logic in a subquery and then join the result instead of doing your big honking sql over and over again in the union.

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what I was looking to do. I moved the logic into a subquery like you suggested and it's not as messy

Answer (score 1):

You can try this -

```
Select Field1, Field2, 
CASE
    WHEN(number IN (1,2,3,4)) then 'Group1 & Group 2' 
    WHEN(number IN (5,6,7,8)) then 'Group1' 
    WHEN(number IN (9,10,11,12)) then 'Group3' 
    ELSE 'Group4' END 
AS Categories
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if your result set has to be in rows, but if you can handle the results in a single row, you can do it like this:

```
SELECT 
    SUM(CASE WHEN Number BETWEEN 1 AND 8 THEN Gross_Sales ELSE 0) AS Group1,
    SUM(CASE WHEN Number BETWEEN 1 AND 4 THEN Gross_Sales ELSE 0) AS Group2,
    SUM(CASE WHEN Number BETWEEN 9 AND 12 THEN Gross_Sales ELSE 0) AS Group3,
    SUM(CASE WHEN Number NOT BETWEEN 1 AND 12 THEN Gross_Sales ELSE 0) AS Group4
FROM MyTable
```

If you need this returned as rows like in your sample output, you can use a pivot function or a common table expression + unions.